# Rest version of "Soap Headers and Handlers"

Tags: java, rest, web-services, soapheader, soaphandler

I have a question about **`Rest web services`**.

In soap, we can use **`SOAP handlers`** to process the request before execution. For example we can parse Soap Headers in Soap Handlers before we are doing the real job.

Is there something like that in Rest services? **`Rest headers`** and **`Rest handlers`**?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about client or server side? Which framework(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are working on client side. If you use jersey framework for rest request , you can use filter implementations. Otherwise If you use apache httpclient, you can use handler implementations.

Jersey docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0540/6nlj9lcpf/index.html

apache docs:https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java